# How to convert a string to pdf file in Python without using temp txt-file on HDD?

Tags: character-encoding, pdf-generation, python-2.7

I have a big library in plain txt-format.
I need to convert these files into pdf format (from **inside** Python script, not from command-line), but previously I need to make some manipulations on the original files' text.
I'm just reading the files' content into string, make the needed changes, and then I want to output the changed string into pdf-file, but **without** creating temporary text file on HDD.
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. BTW, the library is in Russian, so I suppose I'll need to take care of encodings?

Answer (score 0):

use the ReportLab toolkit: http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/
(it is also on PyPi: pip install reportlab; or if you are running Linux use the package manager)

The default built-in fonts of PDF do not support Russian, so you will have to do something
like:

```
canvas.setFont('DejaVuSans',10)
```

(replace 'DejaVuSans' with an installed font name you know has your characters in it).
This will incorporate that font in your PDF and make the resulting file about 20K bigger than without.
It is also possible to generate the PDF to memory, if that is necessary.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Looks like it works ok. Still have some little problem with formatting bu t I believe that now I can solve it. Thanks a lot!